# Special use of plus (+) sign in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Aside from its natural use, i.e. addition of two arguments, you can also use a plus `+` sign in Powershell to do special calls like this one:

```
[System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
```

`UploadFile` is a public static field, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.aspx), hence the double colon `::` - everything is clear so far. But why is `Ftp` class so special, that instead of a dot `.`, it needs a `+`? I could not find any documentation on this part (official or not).

Are there any other uses for `+` except `WebRequestMethods+Ftp`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WebRequestMethods class is a container, it contains the FTP class. FTP itself is a nested-class, and to access the nested-class in PowerShell (or C#, for that matter) you must use the + notation. For more information see [Plus (+) in .NET Class Names](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/plus-in-net-class-names/).

Comment: `...and reflection constructs a mangled name when queried, in accordance with the following conventions...` Well at least this explains the mystery syntax

Comment: Good explanation, but, unfortunately, the link is dead.