# Reference .NET Generic Nested Type in Powershell Core

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

As the title suggests I am trying to reference a Nested Generic Type in Powershell Core.

I found that the `+` sign is used instead of the `.` for accessing a nested type in Powershell... but the syntax doesn't seem to work for "Nested Generic Types"... the compiler doesn't like the code an errors about the syntax.

[Special use of plus (+) sign in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141690/special-use-of-plus-sign-in-powershell)

Has anyone been successful in getting this to work or is it a known limitation?

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string], [int]]+Enumerator] GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: It looks like the syntax might be ```[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[[String],[Int32]]]::new()``` but it doesn't work.  `InvalidOperation: An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..`  (I found this by newing up a dictionary, getting the enumerator and checking it's type info.)

Comment: Thanks... that actually worked for me... I was able to define the appropriate method signature using that syntax. I didn't call `::new()` but instead called `.GetEnumerator()` on the underlying dictionary implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) has provided the solution:

```sh
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[string, int]]
```

returns the type of interest (note that the nested `[...]` around the individual generic type arguments, `string` and `int`, are optional).

That is, before being able to specify *type arguments* in order to *construct* a generic type, you must first specify its *open* form, which requires **specifying the generic *arity* (the count of type arguments, `<n>`) in the form `` `<n> `` following the type name**, namely `` `2 `` in the case of [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2) (expressed in C# notation), using the ***language-agnostic* .NET API notation, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962710/45375)**.

- If no *nested* type (suffixed with `+<typename>`) is involved, specifying the arity is *optional* if all type arguments are specified; e.g., instead of `` [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[string, int]] ``, `[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, int]]` is sufficient.

However, the enumerator type in question has *no public constructor*, so you cannot instantiate it directly; rather, it is the type returned when you call `.GetEnumerator()` on (a constructed form of) the enclosing type, `` [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2] ``; verify with:
`Get-Member -InputObject ([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, int]])::new().GetEnumerator()`